# Expressions contenant le patronyme d'un personnage historique d'expression française ?

Tags: expressions, noms-de-famille

Connaît-on d'autres expressions composées avec le nom de *famille* (par opposition au [prénom](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Idiotismes_avec_pr%C3%A9noms_en_fran%C3%A7ais)) d'un personnage (historique) d'expression française (pour faire changement de nos amis de la [Grèce antique](http://expressions-francaises.e-monsite.com/)) que le « violon d'Ingres »<sup>1</sup> et le « mot de Cambronne »<sup>2</sup> ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Violon d'Ingres*. On doit l'[expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=violon%20d%27Ingres&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cviolon%20d%27%20Ingres%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bviolon%20d%27%20Ingres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BViolon%20d%27%20Ingres%3B%2Cc0) « violon d'Ingres » pour le *talent cultivé en dehors de l'activité principale* ([*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viol%F3n), aussi [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/violon/82085/locution?q=violon%20d%20ingres#177218)) au nom de [*Jean-Auguste-Dominique Ingres*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Auguste-Dominique_Ingres), peintre néo-classique français (1780-1867 ; connu pour ses oeuvres comme [*La Grande Odalisque*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grande_Odalisque), et ses *poses de vénus*, par exemple [*La Source*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Source_(Ingres)) ou [*Vénus anadyomène*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9nus_anadyom%C3%A8ne_%28Ingres%29)). Il se passionnait aussi sérieusement pour le *violon*. On en [atteste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/violon) l'emploi en 1907 chez [C. Farrère](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Farr%C3%A8re) (*Ac. fr.*, élu au [F28](http://academie-francaise.fr/les-immortels/claude-farrere?fauteuil=28&election=28-03-1935) de 1935 jusqu'à sa mort en 1957) dans son polar en Turquie, *L'homme qui assassina* (1906). On note que [P. Picasso](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2009/06/26/630073-montauban-la-grande-odalisque-selon-ingres-par-picasso.html) reprend *La Grande Odalisque* en 1907. Enfin j'ai trouvé le propos de [Réjean Ducharme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9jean_Ducharme) dans [*La fille de Christophe-Colomb*](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=pJo2AAAAIAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22R%C3%A9jean%20Ducharme%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22vive%20la%20diff%C3%A9rence%22), 1969, fort à propos : « Vive la différence ! Le violon d'Ingres d'Ingres était le violon. » ...</sub>

---

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Mot de Cambronne*. L'[expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mot%20de%20Cambronne&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmot%20de%20Cambronne%3B%2Cc0) le « [mot de Cambronne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Cambronne#Le_mot_de_Cambronne) » est un euphémisme pour *merde!* ([*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mot), [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mot/52767/locution?q=mot%20de%20cambronne#182264)), que *Pierre Cambronne* (1770-1842 ; général de division) aurait [interjeté](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/merde) (ce qu'il a toujours nié, selon *Wikipédia*) à la bataille de *Waterloo* pour marquer davantage son refus après une déclaration précédente. On réfère aux propos du journaliste Michel Balisson de Rougemon dès le 24 juin 1815, ou à l'[histoire](https://books.google.com/books?id=x_IllUi-QVYC&pg=PA158&dq=%22Le%20Journal%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral%20de%20France%22%2024%20juin%201815&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixw46x1dTJAhXryoMKHTfZB5gQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Le%20Journal%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral%20de%20France%22%2024%20juin%201815&f=false) du [général Michel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude-%C3%89tienne_Michel), et au fait que Victor Hugo lui aussi fasse cette attribution à Cambronne, en particulier par une allusion dans *Les Misérables* etc.. Au-delà du refus catégorique d'obtempérer que le général interjeta, on a une référence [particulière](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merde#En_Europe_francophone) dans l'univers du théâtre, et la périphrase y est d'usage (comparer [*dire merde à quelqu'un*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/merde/50601/locution), par antiphrase) pour souhaiter *bonne chance* à quelqu'un.</sub>

Comment: Existe-t-il un nom pour ce procédé ? Est-ce une figure de style ?

Comment: Une pagnolade ?

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres -- Il y en a moinssoient, notre ego en est pantois. La raison en commentaire, il faut demander. Sinon se taire, ne pas s'abaisser pour être à nouveau blessé.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un **[coup de Jarnac](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_de_Jarnac)** est un coup violent, habile et imprévu. Il a pris une connotation de coup déloyal ou pernicieux, qui n'existait pas à l'origine. Dans son sens premier et d’escrime, il s’agit d’un coup à l’arrière du genou ou de la cuisse, rendu célèbre par Guy Chabot de Jarnac, qui le porte lors d'un duel en 1547.

Une **[vérité de La Palice](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapalissade)** (ou lapalissade) consiste à affirmer une évidence immédiatement perceptible, ce qui déclenche en général le rire de l'interlocuteur. Le seigneur de La Palice, Jacques de Chabannes, après s'être illustré dans les campagnes de François Ier en Italie, trouva la mort à Pavie en 1525. Une chanson fut composée en son honneur par ses soldats qui voulaient signifier par là qu'il s'était battu jusqu'au moment de sa mort, mais les paroles furent ensuite détournées par l'académicien Bernard de La Monnoye au XVIIIe siècle, qui en fit ressortir le côté simple, dont on ne retint plus que la naïveté.

```
 "Monsieur d'La Palice est mort 
 Est mort devant Pavie 
 Un quart d'heure avant sa mort
 Il faisait encore envie".
```

Plus rare, la **cour du roi Pétaud** (ou une pétaudière) est un lieu de désordre et de confusion. 
Le roi Pétaud était le chef de la corporation des mendiants, au Moyen-Age. Par dérision, car Pétaud vient du latin peto demander l'aumône ou bien pêter. Molière cite dans Tartuffe la cour du roi Pétaud "On n'y respecte rien ; chacun y parle haut".

Comment: « Il est mort d'un arrêt de cœur » est un peu moins evidente peut-etre comme vérité de ce genre, mais elle n'est pas mal non plus je trouve! cc; @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres

Answer (score 3):

La *[Pêche Melba](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%AAche_Melba)* est un dessert créé en 1893 par Auguste Escoffier pour la soprano colorature australienne Nellie Melba.

Bien qu'il ne s'agisse pas  de "La pêche *de* Melba", Melba est le seul nom connu (et qui n'a aucun lien avec l'arboriculture ou la pâtisserie) associé à ce fruit.

---

*Complément : [Pépinière d'expressions](http://alyon.org/litterature/regles/origine_des_expressions.html)*

> - L'âne de *Buridan*,
> - Soutenir un Fort *Chabrol*,
> - Ce chien de *Jean de Nivelle*, qui s'en va quand on l'appelle
> - Le grain de sable de *Pascal*

L'âne de Buridant
soutint un Fort Chabrol,
<sup>... mais</sup> 
Le grain de sable de Pascal
<sup>... pris la forme du</sup>
Chien de Jean de Nivelle
<sup>... Et l'âne pleura, pleura... Hi han</sup>

Comment: La pêche Melba, c'est ma madeleine de Proust !

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres La madeleine de Proust n'est pas, mais alors pas du tout un prénom. Elle a même failli être une biscotte ... http://next.liberation.fr/livres/2015/10/21/la-biscotte-de-proust-du-pain-benit-pour-les-fetichistes-litteraires_1407845

Comment: Pas seulement, il s'agit bien d'une expression bien connue qui désigne un souvenir d'enfance à partir duquel beaucoup d'autres souvenirs de cette époque révolue remontent à la mémoire.

Comment: Merci pour les ajouts ! De Joyeuses Fêtes !

Answer (score 3):

D’après le dernier paragraphe de [cet article {trouvé dans ‘Gala’}](http://www.gala.fr/l_actu/news_de_stars/les_rothschild_puissance_et_gloire_d_une_dynastie_58940) :

« Depuis trois siècles, «**[riche comme Roth­schild](http://www.lesechos.fr/idees-debats/crible/021131076046-riche-comme-rothschild-1127558.php)** » est une expression devenue courante. » (exemple « à la une » sur ‘Les Echos’)

«L’article (Gala) parle de « trois siècles » car en 1815 (après la défaite de Napoléon I<sup>er</sup>):

> à Paris, James –qui a créé sa propre banque sous la Restauration–
>   fait fortune dans les chemins de fer, la navigation, les charbonnages
>   et la métallurgie.

(pour [tenter de] dire que le nom et la richesse des « Rothschild » [et donc l’expression] sont [ou au moins, ont des origines] françaises).

Answer (score 3):

J'ai récemment lu une phrase contenant l'expression suivante :
[inventaire à la Prévert](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/inventaire_%C3%A0_la_Pr%C3%A9vert)

Qui signifie selon le Wiktionnaire :

> Liste, énumération hétéroclite, inventaire qui n'a apparemment ni queue ni tête.

Et fait référence au poète [Jacques Prévert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pr%C3%A9vert)

Answer (score 0):

Je viens de tomber sur l'expression suivante : [une victoire à la Pyrrhus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoire_%C3%A0_la_Pyrrhus)

Selon Wikipedia :

> L'expression est une allusion au roi Pyrrhus Ier d'Épire, dont l'armée souffrit des pertes irremplaçables quand il défit les Romains pendant sa guerre en Italie à la bataille d'Héraclée (sur le territoire de la cité d'Héraclée de Lucanie) en 280 av. J.-C. et à celle d'Ausculum en 279 av. J.-C.

Comment: Oui, mais la question précise: personnage historique d'expression **française**.

Comment: @jlliagre : il y a ambiguïté, est-ce le personnage historique qui doit être français ou l'expression ? ou les deux ?

Comment: Il n'y a aucune ambiguïté dans la question.

Comment: @jlliagre : _Personnage historique français ayant donné lieu à une expression_ serait moins ambigüe, car il y a ambigüité. C'est à l'auteur de la question de juger de la pertinence de la réponse. Bonne journée à vous.

Comment: L'auteur de la question à supprimé son compte. Personnage historique français est plus restrictif que personnage historique d'expression française. La réponse "victoire à la Pyrrhus* a déjà été proposée il y a quatre ans puis effacée rapidement par son auteur quand il a relu avec plus d'attention la question qui exclut de manière très claire les personnages de l'antiquité et de la Grèce antique en particulier.